# Sort by date in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a VBA function that selects data from an outside source and inserts it into an excel sheet. I want to be able to sort by the date with the most recent date appearing first in the list. I am not sure how to add this function (or what function to add) to my already existing function so it continues through the loops.

```
Sub getDividends()

    Dim QuerySheet As Worksheet
    Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim Symbol As String
    Dim qurl As String
    Dim nQuery As Name

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set DataSheet = ActiveSheet

    StartDate = DataSheet.Range("B2").Value
    EndDate = DataSheet.Range("B3").Value
    Symbol = DataSheet.Range("B4").Value
    Range("C7").CurrentRegion.ClearContents

'construct the URL for the query

    qurl = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" & Symbol
    qurl = qurl & "&a=" & Month(StartDate) & "&b=" & Day(StartDate) & _
        "&c=" & Year(StartDate) & "&d=" & Month(EndDate) - 1 & "&e=" & _
        Day(EndDate) & "&f=" & Year(EndDate) & "&g=v&ignore=.csv"
        Range("e1") = qurl

QueryQuote:
         With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & qurl, Destination:=DataSheet.Range("C7"))
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            .SaveData = True
        End With

        Range("C7").CurrentRegion.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C7"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, other:=False

        Range(Range("C7"), Range("C7").End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "mmm d, yyyy"
        Range(Range("D7"), Range("G7").End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "$0.00"


With ThisWorkbook
    For Each nQuery In Names
        If IsNumeric(Right(nQuery.Name, 1)) Then
            nQuery.Delete
        End If
    Next nQuery
End With

'turn calculation back on
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Range("C8:D500").Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("C8"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
Range("C1").Select
Selection.ColumnWidth = 17.7

getPrice

Range("B4").Select

End Sub

Sub getPrice()

    Dim QuerySheet As Worksheet
    Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim qurl As String
    Dim i As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set DataSheet = ActiveSheet

Range("A7").CurrentRegion.ClearContents

qurl = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + Range("B4") + "&f=l1"

QueryQuote:
         With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & qurl, Destination:=DataSheet.Range("A7"))
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            .SaveData = True
        End With

        Range("A7").CurrentRegion.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A7"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, other:=False


'turn calculation back on
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Range("A1").Select
Selection.ColumnWidth = 20

End Sub

Sub getaLL()

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, n As Integer

    n = Range("E3")
    j = 9

Range("I2").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
Range("A5") = "Retrieving Dividends ..."
For i = 1 To n

Range("B4") = Cells(1 + i, 7)
getDividends
Cells(1, j) = Range("C5")

Range("C7:D500").Select
Selection.Copy
Cells(2, j).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False
Selection.ColumnWidth = 12

j = j + 2
Next i

Range("A5").Select
Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: i would suggest to look at the following link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx autofilter would be the right option to filter it by date